# How to configure load balancing with 2 master node in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, load-balancing, high-availability

I need to configure High Availability for our big project which has actually 70-80 spring-boot applications.

We have a jenkins master with slaves and I need one more master (I have enough VM for slaves and a master) and I need to configure them with load balancer.

Do you have any idea, how can I do that?

Comment: I [edited your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing), improving either its formatting, or [its quality](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/02/05/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/) to help people understanding your question, and to help you to get an appropriate answer.
But you still may need to add further information for your question to become fully solvable.

Comment: You can look into nginx which supports load balancing among multiple servers.